# officeJS Word add-in - Inserting header ooxml adding an extra line to the header

Tags: office-js, word-2016

I am trying to read the header ooxml, modifying it and inserting back to the header. But on inserting, somehow it adds an extra line to the header. Even If I just read the ooxml and insert it back without any changes, it adds an extra line in the header. What am I missing ?

Here is my code

```
Word.run(function (context) {

        var docSections = context.document.sections; 

        context.load(docSections, 'body/style');

        return context.sync().then(function () {                


            // get header
            var header = docSections.items[0].getHeader("primary");


            var ooxml = header.getOoxml();

            // another sync to get the OOXML value
            return context.sync().then(function () {


                // get ooxml value and insert it
                var headerVal = ooxml.value;
                header.insertOoxml(headerVal, 'Replace');


                return context.sync().then(function () {
                    callBackFunc({
                        isError: false
                    });
                });

            });
        });
    })
```

Comment: can you please provide in what platform and version you are observing this? thanks!!

Comment: Windows 7, Word 2016 (16.0.4639.1000) , Api 1.1

Comment: just answered below

Answer (score 0):

ok you are in MSI.  in MSI SKUs that's a known issue, one that was fixed for Office 365 SKUs, shipped as part of 1.2 APIs.
If your target release is MSI then you need to remove the paragraph after inserting OOXML (you can check if 1.2 is supported before doing that)

Comment: so are you saying it is fixed in 1.2 API ?

Comment: regarding removing the extra paragraph, so after inserting OOXML, I need to get all the paragraphs of the header and delete the last one. Is that correct ?